# Exclude CSS files from autocomplete in PhpStorm

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm, code-completion

When I developing a Laravel, Inertia, and Svelte, CSS classes from `node_modules` somehow are included at my PhpStorm autocomplete. It's kinda annoying since I don't need them.

Is there any ways to exclude this files from included to autocomplete?

[image: My Swal module CSS detected in autocomplete]

Comment: One suggestion: right click on a file and choose to override its file type (make it Plain Text). This way even if the file is indexed it will not participate in code completion. Not ideal but something that works.

Comment: I had similar issue on Webstorm. LazyOne's method worked.